# Telerik RadGridView in WPF: GetRowForItem method returns null after calling SortDescriptors.Reset()

Tags: wpf, multithreading, telerik, radgridview

The GetRowForItem method returns null after calling grid.SortDescriptors.Reset(). The following code is an example of a button click event that gets the row for a selected item:

```
    private void GetRowForSelectedItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.clubsGrid.SortDescriptors.Reset();
        var r = this.clubsGrid.GetRowForItem(this.clubsGrid.SelectedItem);
        MessageBox.Show(r.ToString());
    }
```

The value of r is null.

Comment: Here is the thread on the Telerik forum regarding this issue: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/gridview/keyboard-focus-within-hierarchychildtemplate.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is occurring is the Grid.SortDescriptors.Reset() method is executing on the UI thread and hasn't finished by the time the GetRowForItem method is called. Here is a workaround that seems to work well for me. I'm calling the SortDescriptors.Reset() method, and then calling BeginInvoke (with DispatcherPriority of Input) to make the call to the GetRowForItem method.

```
 private void GetRowForSelectedItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.clubsGrid.SortDescriptors.Reset();

        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(() =>
        {
            var r = this.clubsGrid.GetRowForItem(this.clubsGrid.SelectedItem);
            MessageBox.Show(r.ToString());
        }));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I had a similar problem and this solution fixed the exception that I've got.